# Graphics acceleration for onboard HP 96 MB graphic card

Tags: windows-7, graphics, intel-graphics

Can I download an Intel graphics driver for windows 7 on a 96 MB graphic card? I am running windows 7 ultimate. Everything is working fine except graphics movies don't play properly and it tends to slow down windows animations Any help?

Comment: you can always download drivers from the motherboard manufactures website.or if the card is from other manufacturer you can lookup for the drivers in their website.if you describe the name of your card, someone will be able to give good suggestions.

Comment: which onboard graphic do you use? Open DeviceManager and post the Hardware IDs (Vendor, Device) so that we can look into a PCI Database.

Comment: @magicandre1981The Hardware IDs are as follows:         PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2572&SUBSYS_12BC103C&REV_02,  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2572&SUBSYS_12BC103C, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2572&CC_30000, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2572&CC_0300

Answer (score 0):

`PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2572` = `Intel(R) 82865G Graphics Controller` which doesn't provide DirectX9, so there are no WDDM drivers. In this case you can only try the old XP drivers, but you don't get Aero Glass.